# File `latexmk.sty' not found

Tags: packages, document-classes

I'm not very familiar with tex, but I have a question about an error I get:

```
File `latexmk.sty' not found.
```

The error is caused by this line:

```
\RequirePackage{latexmk}
```

This line is in a documentclass I use.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

EDIT:

I created a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{report}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\begin{document}
Lipsum
\end{document}
```

When I compile this I get an error:

```
File `mfirstuc.sty' not found. \RequirePackage
```

Regards,

Stille Bever

Comment: As far as I know `latexmk` is no `sty` package but a command to simplify the compilation of `.tex` files. `\RequirePackage{latexmk}` seems to be rubbish

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `latexmk` is a compiling tool, but usually not used as package. Please provide us with a MWE to get further assistance (probably a description of your setup could be useful too).

Comment: Exactly which latex installation are you using? Latexmk will probably not work out of the box on miktex, but does work out of the box with a full texlive or mactex installation

Comment: Miktex and texlive were both installed, I removed miktex from the sytem. Now the problem with the example I gave is gone. However when I add the line \usepackage{glossaries} just below the documentclass I get the following error: File `mfirstuc.sty' not found. \RequirePackage

Comment: that package is https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc?lang=en where it shows it is in both texlive and miktex so  you can just install it via tlmgr if you did not do a full install originally.

Comment: When I install it with texlive I get: tlmgr.pl install: package already present: mfirstuc. But in TeXstudio it still gives the same error

Comment: then your setup in texstudio has the wrong paths set

Comment: It is the latex compiler which cannot find the package. What should I change to let it know where he can find the package?

Comment: I found a solution to this problem, by deleting texstudion.ini in the appdata folder. After that I manually removed everything installed by MikTex.  The next error I get is: Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.

Comment: I got the whole thing working, what I did was adding "--shell-escape" to the pdflatex command. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @StilleBever Would you put your comment as an answer, which can be accepted so this question can then disappear from the unanswered queue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the whole thing working, what I did was adding "--shell-escape" to the pdflatex command. Thanks for all your help!